# What is the formula of Standard Deviation (Discrete and Continuous Series) in terms of Population and Sample?

Tags: math, statistics, probability

I know SD ungrouped data formula

in terms of Population SD =

[image]

in terms of Sample SD =

[image]

I am searching for Grouped Data (Discrete and Continuous) formula if anybody would help me it will be very helpful.

Comment: What research have you done on this issue? [Here is Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=standard+deviation+grouped+data&form=EDGEAR&qs=AS&cvid=848118d6387d4899aeb15a9ba6ef2813&pq=standard+deviation+group): I'm sure you can do the same for Google or other search engine.

Comment: There is not a single search result which describes SD formula for Population or SD formula for Sample. Probably I am missing something that's why i am here

Answer (score 0):

(I'll do what I can without MathJax.)

If the values are

[image]

and the frequencies for those values are

[image]

Then if those are the entire population,

[image]

[image]

[image]

If those are just a sample, we have the same formula for N, but

[image]

[image]

If *x* is a continuous function of *t* and are the values while *f(t)* are the densities of *x* we have

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not see how you could have a grouped, continuous sample.

I'm sure you can see how to write code to implement these. Note however that these are definitions, not computation strategies: there are more efficient ways to calculate some of them, such as standard deviation.